# Yii2 PostgreSql how to add default value from another column on addColumn in migration

Tags: postgresql, yii2, migration, yii2-advanced-app

I have PostgreSQL DB table with 4 columns ex. col1, col2, col3, col4.
Col3 is unique indexed. I want to add new column with notNull and default value of col3 as after that I want to make newly created column also unique?
Is it possible to achieve this by simple Yii2 migration?

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** get what you want directly; the default expression cannot reference a another column. What you can do is make the new column *unique* but null-able, then update the values, and finally make the column *not null*. If needed you can create a trigger to maintain the new column.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0Mn3p5TT))

```
alter table a_table add new_col text unique;

update a_table set new_col = col3; 

-- clean up any null values in new_col; (there is nothing saying
alter table a_table alter column new_col set not null;
```

If need long term the create a trigger function and trigger to manage `new_col`:

```
-- set new_col column 
create or replace function new_col()
  returns trigger 
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    new.new_col = coalesce(new.new_col, new.col3, old.new_col, '');   -- always on update ???   
    return new;     
end;
$$; 

create trigger a_table_biur
  before insert or update
  on a_table 
  for each row execute function new_col();
```

The trigger function used the minimum logic necessary, and will not satisfy every condition. You will need to evaluate that.